# Physical interpretation of propagator pole

Tags: quantum-field-theory, feynman-diagrams, singularities, propagator, s-matrix-theory

In QFT the propagator is divergent for the on-shell momentum of the particles. When e.g. calculating the amplitude for a box loop, the propagator diverges for on-shell particles running in the box-loop.

Is there a physical interpretation for this divergent behavior?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, there is and you can see it directly in the [Källen-Lehmann spectral representation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K%C3%A4ll%C3%A9n%E2%80%93Lehmann_spectral_representation). I won't give you the derivation because it's quite lengthy but when you take this representation for the propagator you can divide the contribution from the one particle states from the contribution from the many particle state in the following manner (for a scalar field, but the results stays the same for spinors and vectors)

$$G(q^2) = \frac{Zi}{q^2-m^2+i\epsilon}+\int_{M_{\text{th}}^2}^\infty\mathrm{d}\mu^2\frac{i\rho(\mu^2)}{q^2-\mu^2+i\epsilon}$$

when you look at the analytic structure of the propagator as a function of $q^2\in\mathbb{C}$ you clearly see a pole given by the physical mass and a cut related to the multiparticle states. In the image there're also highlighted the possible poles due to bound states.

[image]

This is quite an interesting result since gives you a correspondence between the physical mass and the unique pole in the propagator. All the multiparticle states do not give singular contributions to the propagator. And most importantly, this result does not rely on perturbation theory. It is go general that it was used bu Weinberg, Goldstone and Salam to give a non-perturbative proof to Goldstone theorem.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! But it seems that this answer goes right over my head. I am still a beginner to QFT. Is it possible to elaborate this answer to a more phenomenological point where it is understandable for someone who is not yet "fluent" in the technicalities of QFT. If not, i go on in my studying and get back to the answer when i improved my formal understanding.

Comment: I think that the topic is a little bit more advanced, but i feel that if you look on some books on QFT, Peskin & Schroder or any other, you could find the informations you look for. Even online there are some rather interesting notes on QFT which treat the KL-representation.

Comment: Okay, then i will do some more studying until i reach a level more suitable to my question. I just thought that there might be a very phenomenological answer to it since the divergence occurs exactly at the point where the four momentum of virtual particles become physical solutions to their EOM.

Comment: Yeah, surely there is but atm I cannot think of one! I'll think about it and get back if a get anything!

Answer (score 3):

I might be wrong about the physical interpretation, but I always thought of it this way: the propagator in configuration space $G(x-y)$ can be interpreted as the probability amplitude for a particle to be created at point $x$, propagate and anihilate at $y$. Then if you think *a la Feynman*, the path a particle can take between two points is *any* path in configuration space. In my opinion this necessarly includes paths in which the momentum of the particle does not necessarly need to be on-shell. Then when I think about the representation of $G(x-y)$ in momentum space it becomes obvious for me that we are doing a summation over the momentum's of all this paths, including all this off-shell momentum's. Then I interpret the terms in the summation as follows: the more close the momentum is to be on-shell, the bigger will be its contribution to the integral value. Then what the integral is telling me is that the paths that are more/less *probable* (the terms that will contribute more to the value of the integral) are those in which the momentum is close/far to be on-shell. Whoa!